# How do I change my display name on Google?

Tags: google-drive, google-account-profile

The name displayed on my Google account is someone else's so I need to change it, however I can't figure out how to do that. I deleted my Google+ account in the hopes that that would do it but it hasn't. When I go to any Google account settings it has my correct name but is not using that when I share documents with people.

Comment: Displayed where, exactly? Are you logged in to two different accounts? Is this just a regular Google account or Google Apps?

Comment: If i click on my email address displayed in the top right hand corner of Google, the name above my email, and then when I share documents on Google Drive it also comes up as the different name. I'm just logged onto one account.

Comment: How, exactly, are you sharing documents? (Which options are you using?) Are they just regular Google Docs? Are you using the new Google Drive? I'm trying to see if I can replicate what you're seeing. Screen shots would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive and the Google Docs Editors apps (Documents, Drawings, Sheets and Slides) use the First Name and Last Name set for the Google account as the display name.

The Google Account settings page have a first name and a last name fields for accounts without a Google+ profile. To edit the first name and last name go to http://myaccount.google.com, then to Your Personal Info.

In some cases could be alternate usernames, like when the user set nicknames in Google Groups.

For accounts with a Google+, go to http://plus.google.com then click in the dropdown at the left and select Profile.

**References**

- [Keeping your personal information private and safe—and putting you
  in control - Official Google
  Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2015/06/privacy-security-tools-improvements.html)
- [Edit your basic account information - Google Accounts
  Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en)
- [Alternate usernames - Google Accounts
  Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/70206?hl=en)
- [Create or change your Google+ profile name - Google Plus
  Help](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271?hl=en)